# find the value of y(x) at $\pi$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The value of $y(x)$ at $x=\pi$ when $y''+f(x)y=0$ and 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
-1&\;{\rm for}\;0\leq x\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\\
 1&\;{\rm for}\;\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\leq\pi
\end{cases}
$$
given  that $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=0$

1. $\sinh\frac{\pi}{2}$
2. $\cosh\frac{\pi}{2}$
3. $1$
4. $0$

in this question the function $f(x)$ is breaking at $\frac{\pi}{2}$. I know the  method of solving simple equations, but how to solve this question. Please help.

Comment: Solve it first for the interval up to the break point, and then use that result to give you an initial value for the second interval.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that the general solution for $y''-y=0$ is
$$
y(x)=A\cosh(x)+B\sinh(x)
$$
and for $y''+y=0$ is
$$
y(x)=C\cos(x)+D\sin(x).
$$
Now you need to find the constants so that the initial conditions and the continuity at $x=\frac\pi2$ are satisfied.

---

By the initial conditions, $$y(x)=\cosh(x)$$ on $[0,\frac\pi2]$.

On the second segment $[\frac\pi2,\pi]$ one then gets by
$$
y(x)=y(x_1)\cos(x-x_1)+y'(x_1)\sin(x-x_1)
$$
using trigonomentric symmetries for $x_1=\frac\pi2$
$$
y(x)=\cosh(\frac\pi2)\sin(x)-\sinh(\frac\pi2)\cos(x)
$$

Comment: does it continous at pi\2?

Comment: Yes, the pieces apart from the subdivision points are continuous by construction.

Comment: can you please solve this?